Why do some translations render "ἰδοὺ" as "suddenly" and "look" instead of the original rendering of "behold"?
I've noticed a number of modern translations rendering ἰδοὺ  as "look" or "suddenly".
Shouldn't ἰδοὺ always be translated as "behold"?
I find the other renderings to be unsatisfactory as they lose the powerful weight of the word "behold".
The choice of "look" does not work in every verse, and neither does "suddenly"; but the word "behold" always seems to fit the context wherever ἰδοὺ is written in the passages.
Do you think that this Greek word should only always remain translated as "behold" in English translations?
Here is are two case examples (Matt 28:9, Jn 1:29) among dozens of others:
NIV

Suddenly Jesus met them. “Greetings,” he said. They came to him,
clasped his feet and worshiped him.

ESV

And behold, Jesus met them and said, “Greetings!” And they came up and took hold of his feet and worshiped him.

NIV

The next day John saw Jesus coming toward him and said, “Look, the
Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!

ESV

The next day he saw Jesus coming toward him, and said, “Behold,
the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!


When did you last hear someone use the word "behold" in general conversation?

@JoshuaB "behold!" is archaic "look!", it could be also "lo!". "Suddenly" is not bad either.

The New Testament was written in Koine Greek, meaning the Greek used as the common language.  Biblia Sacra Vulgata means the Holy Bible in the common language.  The Scriptures should be translated in the common language that people use.

Both of these common languages were international languages.  That makes you wonder if the best English translation would be a very simple English with words commonly used internationally.

@PerryWebb - The best translation is the one that properly conveys this Greek word.

But to properly convey the Greek word, the translation must be understood by the reader. That includes the person reading the Bible for the first time without someone else explaining it,

@PerryWebb I think everybody knows what "behold" means, for crying out loud!

The most helpful way to show this is the definition of the word as supplied by BDAG for ἰδού (idou):

prompter of attention, behold, look, see, it serves to enliven a narrative


(a) by arrousing attention of hearers, eg, Luke 22:10, John 4:35, 1 Cor 15;51, 2 Cor 5:17, James 5:9, Jude 14, Rev 1:7, 9:12, 11:14, etc
(b) by introducing something new or unusual, (see BDAG for the dozens of examples)
(c) as a call to closer consideration and contemplation, remember, consider, etc, eg, Matt 10:16, 11:8, 22:4, Mark 14:41, Luke 2:48, 7:25, 1:44, etc.


marker of strong emphasis, used with a noun without a finite verb as in a colloquial "see", "what do you know", "of all things", "wonder of wonders", ... eg, Matt 3:17, 12:10, 11:19, Luke 7:34, 5:12, 18, 7:37, 11:31, 13:11, 17:21, 19:2, 20, 22:38, 47, 23:50, Acts 8:27, etc.

Thus, translating ἰδού as "behold" does not come near the full meaning of the word at all!!  Thus, modern translation show the full meaning and variation in the word.  In short, there is no single word in English that exactly corresponds to this Greek word and so it must be translated by a variety of words depending on context.

I hesitate to attempt an answer to the OP question since it, pardon me, drips with translation philosophy presuppositions.  Whoever tagged with ‘translation-philosophy’ nailed it.  So, I’ll offer one characteristic that should be a criterion for a good translation philosophy.  And, while not a complete answer, it seeks to directly answer your “Why do some translations...” question.
The scriptural basis for my answer is 1 Cor. 14:19 (and the entire chapter, actually):

Yet in the church I had rather speak five words with my understanding,
that by my voice I might teach others also, than ten thousand words in
an unknown tongue. (KJV)

or more modern translation

nevertheless, in church I prefer to speak five words with my mind so
that I may instruct others also, rather than ten thousand words in a
tongue. (NASB20)

or less literal

But in a church meeting I would rather speak five understandable words
to help others than ten thousand words in an unknown language. (NLT)

The Greek dative phrase, translated as “with my understanding/mind,” τῷ νοΐ μου, is very close to the meaning signaled by a single English word, ‘intelligible’1.  A word associated with ‘intelligent’ and yet it connects with semantic components related to speech and writing, which is exactly what Paul is talking about.  He’s saying, “I would rather speak five intelligible words in order to inform others...”  And that’s how I would translate this text.  The dative means that the speaking is relative to the mind.
No matter how one understands γλῶσσα (tongue/language), Paul’s point is clearly that communication that is related to the Bible and which is within a community of believers is to be clear.  It’s to be intelligible.  It’s to communicate.
Now, there are three components of this clarity that should be noted:

The main component is the element of clarity itself.  Somewhat ironic when one considers the venue of my answer.  A venue filled with questions, rightfully so (it’s StackExchange!!), that reflect, “What does X mean?”  The irony strongly suggests that translation is difficult, and that achieving clarity forever requires a near Herculean effort.  And yet Paul is clear about being clear.  The bugler must make a clarion call (verse 8).
It’s to be rational.  Paul mentioned “the mind”.  When ‘clarity’ and ‘rational’ are combined, ‘intelligibility’ is generated.  So, accuracy of translation is quite important2. The meaning of the five words in Paul’s mind must be accurately reproduced in order for Paul’s mind to be productive.  But, to convey what is accurate requires clarity which is achieved by the use of the linguistic components naturally provided by the language.  Accuracy, clarity, and naturalness are tied together to produce intelligibility.  By ‘naturally’, see next.
It’s in reference to a group of people.  So, it’s inherently associated with the linguistic conventions of a community (I’m referring to naturalness, again).  This communal nature of the communication is brought out several times in 1 Cor. 14. It’s a very important point for Paul.  And by the expression “linguistic conventions” I’m referring to all that stuff you, I, others on this list, a waiter/waitress, a co-worker, etc, have tacitly agreed to.  Things like the word ‘nature’ conveys a certain set of senses, a preposition functions a certain way, the capital letter at the beginning of a sentence is semantically relevant, and even that little dot at the end of a sentence conveys meaning.  And these conventions are different with different languages.  Some languages don’t have prepositions, a Central American language has something like 20% whistles, some languages don’t code time into their syntax, some languages have no word for ‘brother’ or ‘sister’, etc.  In order to communicate to and within a group of people, you have to use the language of that people.  Communication is always group oriented (as much as I like to talk to myself).

So, why did they translate ἰδοὺ the way they did?  Out of obedience to Scripture so that Scripture itself is clear to as many in the intended audience as possible.  Is translating ἰδοὺ as ‘behold’ more correct?  Perhaps for Joshua B.  But, given the linguistic conventions of the English language, it’s not more correct for the vast majority of people.  Some wouldn’t even know what ‘behold’ could mean.  Sadly, for many, ‘behold’ would convey a sense of some irrelevant time in the distant past or a Star Trek, other-world, fantasy civilization.  That is, the meaning would be that the Bible is irrelevant.  There’s more than just lexical semantics going on in the use of a word.  There’s also Pragmatic (aka contextual) meaning.
My answer then is:  So that the meaning is clearly conveyed to the intended community.
Since your question is heavily translation-philosophy oriented, I’d like to pose a question back to you.  Obviously, you won’t have the opportunity to answer here.  So, my purpose then, if I may, is to get you to think, at least a little, along a different translation-philosophy pathway.

If words in one language can easily be represented by words in a
different language, then would God’s action at the Tower of Babel have
brought about His intention to end the construction?  Would separating
people into different language groups have permanently succeeded?

There’s a very interesting corollary to that question based on Acts 2 where construction of the Church is started.
1 Notice I said, ‘it signals’ and not ‘it means’.  Words signal meaning, they do not contain meaning.  From a cognitive linguistic or even neurological viewpoint it is better to think of the physical word as “turning on meaning.”
2 My Epistemological assumption is that rationality implies that truth is coherent, I’m far from a Post-modernist.

Tell me what you think sounds better: "Suddenly, he is coming with the clouds", or "Look, he is coming with the clouds", or "Behold, he is coming with the clouds"? (The 3rd option feels the most relevant)

@JoshuaB Having grown up with and still using the KJV, I think there's very little distinction between them. "Behold" has a more formal "feel" to it, because it's used almost exclusively in early modern English (i.e. Shakespeare, KJV, Tyndale's translation of the Bible, etc.), but "look" seems most inherently understandable to current modern audiences.

@Jed Schaaf - People still throw up their hands in jest and say, "Behold!" when exulting somebody in a roundabout way to mock Christ.

@JoshuaB Itym "exalt." I've never seen that, but even if it is a common thing, I think you have it reversed. People say "Behold!" ("Look at this!") to call attention to something. That's all that Pilate did with Christ. There was nothing special with the meaning then, and there's nothing special with the meaning now. I doubt most people today would be thinking of Ecce Homo when they say "Behold!" The only irony would be calling attention to themselves or something silly using a more "formal" word.

@JedSchaaf - I analyzed the exactly 200 instances of this particular Greek word within the New Testament texts, and I must say that the term is best only translated as "Behold" and nothing else than that. When this word is outright removed, or replaced with something like "Look", or "See", or "Suddenly", it completely loses it's narrative impact in my sure opinion.

"Narrative impact" is the reader's response to the text, not the text itself. "Dictionary meaning" makes no difference between "behold" and "look"; both are commands to direct the attention. The only thing left is connotation, and that varies by culture. So, your own culture/upbringing may have left you with an idea that "behold" has a more special meaning than "look," in contrast with mine, that just says that "behold" is more archaic/formal. But we'd be hard-pressed to explain that there's such a significant semantic difference between them that a more common synonym can't be used.

"Behold" has an incredibly punchy weight to it. "Look" or "See" or "Suddenly" just doesn't fell right to me. Some translations even remove the word entirely, thinking that it is insignificant to render in the text. I completely disagree.

@JoshuaB  It's true that the context of Jesus coming on the clouds tends to allow for the use of 'behold'.  But, when I hear 'behold' I expect to see angels appear in the sky.  'Behold' sounds really, really odd when a property owner complains about a fig tree not giving figs.  Luke 13:7, "Behold, for three years now I've found no figs on this tree." (Modified)  Picture a Manager finding that the copier isn't working...again, and say, "Behold, this photocopier isn't working again!"  Sounds, really, really odd.  Picking a specific context doesn't win a general argument.

@MikeSangrey - Stop and look closer: Luke 13:7 is a parable of Christ and the Fig tree represents the root of Israel. The vinedresser represents Christ, and he says "Behold" because a major revelation is taking place for the audience. Do you understand that the term "Behold" is always used in significant locations to magnify an event and acquire our full attention?

@JoshuaB  You're conflating what Luke is saying with what the property owner is saying.  Luke isn't saying "Behold."  It's the man talking to the guy managing the garden. The vast majority of uses of ἰδοὺ are just like this.  They're reported speech.

FWIW:  I think a great majority of the cases of ἰδοὺ could be rendered as "Note this:" or "Note this!"  There certainly are contexts where the "added punch" of the imperative should come through with this exclamative.

@MikeSangrey - I know that. That's why I said that the vinedresser was saying "behold" to him because the Vinedresser is Christ, who is alerting the reader to the profound significance of the Fig tree, representing Israel, being unfruitful. Do you understand this?

One last comment from me that's specific to a hermeneutical principle.  I understand the theological implications of Luke's text addressed to me the reader.  But, to interpret the text accurately, one must recognize the cases of Reported Speech (a technical term).  In other words, the owner wasn't voicing a theological perspective to the gardener.  He's part of the story.  He's an illustration.  It's a speech act within a speech act ('speech act' being another linguistic technical term.)  Or, to say it differently, it's a context inside another context.  The two must be kept separate.


Do you think that this Greek word should only always remain translated
as "behold" in English translations?

No. Varieties of translation are appropriate to render the archaic usages into modern English.
For example take 1 Cor. 15:51

Behold, I show you a mystery: We shall not all sleep; but we shall all
be changed

Many translators render behold as "listen!" This is a not question of reverence but of communicating in modern English what Paul said in Greek. He wasn't asking people to perceive something with their eyes but to understand what he taught. So "look!" would clearly be wrong but "listen!" is appropriate.
Most of the examples that  the OP seems to have in mind involve "behold" as a synonym of "see." In that case "look!" is an appropriate translation. So would phrases like "now see here," or "observe!" In modern English "behold" carries a sense of perceiving something wonderful rather than simply observation. In cases where the the next phrase is indeed wonderful, keeping the word "behold" is a good way to convey that particular sense. The OP did not provide examples for "suddenly" so the context of such translations is unknown.
Conclusion
Why do some translations render "ἰδοὺ" as "suddenly" and "look" instead of the typical reverent rendering of "behold"? - Answer: They usually do this communicate the Greek word in modern English rather that using the archaic "behold" in order to show reverence for tradition.

Dan Fefferman - I wholly disagree. You can see how this particular word is rendered variously as "look", "see", "suddenly", and "listen", but in all instances the word "Behold" fits perfectly. I think that the word "Behold" should be kept in all cases of the appearance of this word!

Dan Fefferman - I give you Matthew 28:9 as an example. Compare the NIV with the ESV: the word "suddenly" is very ugly, but the rendering "Behold" is magnificent and properly fitting.

If you already knew the answer why did you ask? ;-) I often disagree regarding NIV but in this particular case I thing there is a definite sense of suddenness in the story... so "suddenly" does not repulse me.

Dan Fefferman - Knew the answer to what? I asked this question because I am wondering what other scholarly people think about the new disturbing trend for rendering this particular Greek word, and if it is even etymologically viable.

You asked if the word should always be translated as "behold." Your answer is clearly yes. That's OK with me. But do understand that the site has a rule against "opinion based" questions. Personally I don't mind friendly disagreements but sometimes it gets out of hand (which is why moderators often close such questions).

Dan Fefferman - There is no beef between us. I'm just raising the alarm about a particular trend in current translation philosophy that is reducing or even outright scrubbing away an important Greek term that is best translated in English as "Behold" and nothing else.

"Look, I show you a mystery", or "Behold, I show you a mystery"? I prefer the latter.

@DanFefferman  Your use of the exclamation point in translation is spot on.  Many people miss the translation force of punctuation.
